# Performance issue in encryption and decryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I m using this process as given in this [**link**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/05/03/589691.aspx)
 to encrypt my entire database
here i have use 1 master key 2 certificate 2 symmetric key with algorithm aes_256
i build a raw table where i stored all the encrypted data from the main table which is been protected by 1 procedure and 2 trigger one for update and another for insertion then i created a view of the same name of the main table 
plz for more reference check the link

But when i alter the code in my database having data more then 200 tables and few tables containing 1400000 rows each and every query slow down so i need to do performance turning. for what i m looking into some alternative for big database 
i know that encrypting entire database will slow down but it is the requirement and delay can't be accepted above 10 sec but now i m having above 2 min 
suggest me what to do

---

[Please check the code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2006/05/03/589691.aspx) . and suggested me about any performance tuning that i can work on it 
 i thought of changing in sql query changed in where clause as we will convert the sql where condition statement into encrypted form n check into the row table but thing is dat in certain cases the application want entire tables in hand that will again cause error

Comment: Are you querying against encrypted columns?

Comment: Are you using sql2005 or sql2008? There are different encryption options in each.

Comment: i encrypting the entire database as that is the requirement. i m using 2005 but i have also checked with 2008 no doubt the same approach if there is ne better plz let me know

Comment: yes all the queries are against encrypted columns as entire database is encrypted

Comment: You've repeatedly said you can't fix the thing that is causing your problem. So you are stuck. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

What to do?

Upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 ENTERPRISE

Then use this database database encryption.

Works. Higher CPU usage but a LOT more efficient than your approach.

Comment: ok i will upgrade my system but plz mention the correct approach if u have any better then this for large database

Comment: Not a lot. At least this keeps the encryption transparent for sql server allowing index use.

Comment: i repeated the entire process in sql2008 it works little bit faster but now the queries are working at a speed of 1:30 min. which is again not possible to implement can u guide me more so that i can come to a solution

Comment: YOU mean you removed your handwritten encryption and moved to database encryption as provided by sqwl server? Just upgrading the database wont solve a bad programmning setup you made.

Comment: no no i installed sql 2008 and created a database implied a fresh table having 14lack of rows then encrypted it which helped me to improve my performance by 30 sec but i want more improvement.

Comment: Well, then go back and read my advice. Your problem is not the database, it is a terrible firing level bad architecture. sql 2008 enterprisea llows you to encrypt the database on the file level, so you can get rid of your bad implementation - and THAT is the problem.